# xcode - How do I keep views locked into portrait mode, but still allow one view to rotate?

Tags: iphone, xcode, orientation, portrait, screen-rotation

I'm having a problem with device rotation.  Except for ONE view, where I show a company splash screen, I want to lock all the remaining app views into Portrait display.  In the project settings the supported orientations are Portrait and LandscapeLeft.  In the 'Company Splash' it works fine and the view rotation is locked into LandscapeLeft no matter how I rotate the device.  On all the other views when I rotate the device to the left the view alters instead of staying in portrait display.  The methods are not even firing?  If I remove Landscape left from the supported Orientations in the project, that screws up the 'Company Splash' view.  I tried changing the `shouldAutorotate` return to `NO`, but that didn't help.  Tried to work my way through the suggestions posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12728390/portrait-and-landscape-mode-in-ios6), but that didn't help.  If I put the following code into my AppDelegate.m, everything is locked into portrait mode and the 'Company Splash' crashes when accessed.

```
-(NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown;
}
```

How do I lock the view into portrait mode no matter how the device is rotated except for the one screen?

** method from the 'Company Splash' view.  Again, works like it is supposed to.

```
-(NSInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft;
}
```

** methods from all the other views, which rotate out of portrait when I don't want them to

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // IOS5 Only returning that it should rotate to potrait
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait);
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    // forcing the rotate IOS6 Only
    return YES;
}

-(NSInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    // return number or enum IOS6 Only
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

I thought maybe it might be because a UITabBarController is the root controller and I'm in a ViewController off of that?  The methods are not even firing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add an observer to the viewDidLoad method of the view you want to rotate like this :

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
 addObserver:self selector:@selector(orientationChanged:)
 name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
 object:[UIDevice currentDevice]];
```

and then set the views according the the landscape view inside the **orientationChanged** method like this :

```
- (void) orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)note{
UIDevice * device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
switch(device.orientation)
{
    case UIDeviceOrientationPortrait:

        break;
    case UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:

        break;
    case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft:

        break;
    case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight:

        break;

    default:
        break;
  };
}
```

Comment: sorry I took so long to respond.  What code do I put in the cases to force the device to a certain rotation?

Comment: Just make your application run on only in portrait mode and in the viewDidLoad methods of the views that you need to rotate add the observer that I have mentioned above and then add the orientationChanged method to that class as well. You will receive a notification when the user rotates the view. So you can set the views for the Landscape mode by code

Comment: didn't turn out to be the problem I was having, but this answer did work.  :)

Comment: @Ushan87 would you please help me to answer this question of mine pleaseeeee here is the link of my question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20603996/how-to-lock-screen-in-portrait-landscape-in-iphone

Answer (score 2):

Slap this method into the view controller you want locked in a certain orientation.

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

just change to the orientation you want (the above locks it in landscape)

Answer (score 0):

maybe u should allow  all orientations, and lock portrait orientation in each class except company splash with

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
    } else {
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
    }
}
```

Comment: I already tried that and it didn't have an effect.  I thought maybe it might be because a UITabBarController is the root controller and I'm in a ViewController off of that? The methods are not even firing?

Comment: sort of figured out what was happening.  Setting the rootViewController to the tabcontroller causes those methods to only fire in the tabControllerClass.m, not in the various tabViewController.m methods.  However , now I have the problem of trying to determine which tab I was viewing when the method fires at the tabcontroller level.  There has to be a more elegant way of dealing with this.