# How to set one of the screens in landscape mode in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios7, uistoryboard

I am developing iphone application in iOS7, i am facing problem in autorotate single screen in landscape mode programatically, while other screens remains in portrait mode.
I am using Story board.

Comment: look @ this- http://stackoverflow.com/a/12728435/1537036

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used following and its working for me in both iOS6 and iOS7 also,try following way :

```
// Added method for Autorotation in you app delegate
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window{
    //NSLog(@"AppDelegate -- supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow");
    if([UICommonUtils isiPhone]){
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }else if(flagOrientationAll == YES){
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
    } 
}
```

Add following in your view controller

```
// set flag "flagOrientationAll" to rotate only one view in your perticular view 
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSLog (@"webViewController -- viewWillAppear");
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
 PlayWithWSWithLibAppDelegate *delegate = (PlayWithWSWithLibAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    delegate.flagOrientationAll = YES;
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSLog (@"webViewController -- viewWillDisappear");
    PlayWithWSWithLibAppDelegate *delegate = (PlayWithWSWithLibAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    delegate.flagOrientationAll = NO;

}
```

Comment: for me UICommonUtils is showing error... can u tell me what is UICommonUtils or do i have to add any header class ?

Comment: It is my class file in which I placed all common methods. like to check device type, rotation etc