# How to force portrait orientation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, landscape-portrait

How to force portrait orientation in `iOS 7` if my application is initially supported for both orientations?

Comment: Not clear can you explain more. Do you need only portrait mode in entire app

Comment: possible duplicate of [Force portrait orientation while pushing from landscape View Controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14633213/force-portrait-orientation-while-pushing-from-landscape-view-controller)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UIViewController *c = [[UIViewController alloc]init];
[self presentViewController:c animated:NO completion:nil];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
```

Comment: May this code not according to apple's standard,not sure..But its good hack.

Comment: When we use this code then our app will not be get approved by the Apple for production.

Comment: Can you explain why this works, please? Also, those methods were deprecated in iOS 6. It's possible that Apple decides to remove them in iOS 8. It wouldn't be the first time a method was deprecated by Apple and removed shortly after.

Comment: @PrabhuNatarajan how you can say that it will get rejected from apple , where you find such statement

Comment: Doesn't work on iOS 8

Comment: flickering effect occur in ios 8.

Answer (score 6):

For the entire app, open the project file, go to the General tab, change the settings:

[image]

Or directly on the Info.plist file:

[image]

If you only want it on a specific view controller, override `supportedInterfaceOrientations`:

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

You can read more about the second method at the official [UIViewController documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Maybe, you'll find a more suitable way for your specific problem.

Comment: Simple and right, but take care to the -(BOOL)shouldAutorotate method.
It must not be overridden, or returns YES, otherwise it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Use Following approach : 
In your app delegate .h

```
@interface PlayWithWSWithLibAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate> {

       BOOL flagOrientationAll;
}

@property (assign) BOOL flagOrientationAll;
```

Add following method in your app delegate .m file

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window{
    //NSLog(@"PlayWithWSWithLibAppDelegate -- supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow");
    if(flagOrientationAll == YES){
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    } else {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
    }
}
```

Implement following way in your view which you want to rotate in both portrait and landscape both for iPhone device

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.tabBarController.delegate = self;

    PlayWithWSWithLibAppDelegate *delegate = (PlayWithWSWithLibAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    delegate.flagOrientationAll = YES;
 }
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    //NSLog(@"viewWillDisappear -- Start");
     PlayWithWSWithLibAppDelegate *delegate = (PlayWithWSWithLibAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        delegate.flagOrientationAll = NO;
}
```

Here is my thread some what similar to your problem : [iOS 7 Interface Orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20422244/ios-7-interface-orientation/20422494#20422494)

Answer (score -3):

```
#import <objc/message.h>

objc_msgSend([UIDevice currentDevice], @selector(setOrientation:), UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);//here you may change your desired Orientation
```