# How to rotate a view inside the tab bar to Portrait

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, uitabbarcontroller

[I have searched Stackoverflow and tried the various solutions/suggestions but haven't yet resolved this. So appreciate if someone can point what am I missing here.]

I have a custom UITabBarController with multiple tabs. Each is a UINavigationController. One of them ViewX is a custom UINavigationController.

I want the ViewX to not rotate to landscape (Only PortraitUp is supported). I was able to achieve that. However if I'm in the landscape mode on some other tab and tap on the tab with ViewX, I want it to rotate back to Portrait, but it stays in landscape.

The CustomUITabController has this code:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return [self.selectedViewController shouldAutorotate];
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return [self.selectedViewController preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation];
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    if (self.selectedViewController)
        return [self.selectedViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

The CustomUINavigationController has this implemented:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    UIInterfaceOrientation interfaceOrientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

I even tried this: This only rotates the Status bar to portrait but the view still remains in Landscape.

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
    UIInterfaceOrientation interfaceOrientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;

    if (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used following method to forcefully set portrait orientation only for one view and its work for me, may be it will be help you

**1, Create one global flag**

```
delegate.flagOrientationAll
```

**2, Add following code in your .m of the you view controller , for you project ViewX.m**

```
// set flag "flagOrientationAll" to rotate only one view in your perticular view 
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSLog (@"webViewController -- viewWillAppear");
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    PlayWithWSWithLibAppDelegate *delegate = (PlayWithWSWithLibAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    delegate.flagOrientationAll = YES;
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSLog (@"webViewController -- viewWillDisappear");
    PlayWithWSWithLibAppDelegate *delegate = (PlayWithWSWithLibAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    delegate.flagOrientationAll = NO;

}
```

**3. for other view you have to set**

```
delegate.flagOrientationAll = NO;
```

**4, Add method for Autorotation in you app delegate**

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window{
    //NSLog(@"AppDelegate -- supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow");
    if(flagOrientationAll == YES){
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }else {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
    } 
}
```

Here my POST : [How to set one of the screens in landscape mode in iphone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19422373/how-to-set-one-of-the-screens-in-landscape-mode-in-iphone/19423135#19423135)

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. Unfortunately it didn't work either. The solution is similar to what I had earlier but just at the appDelegate level. I still tried but it didn't work. The application:supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow: gets called and I see the value being returned is UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait but that didn't help.

The issue is if my device is in landscape mode, I'm in a different tab with the view also in landscape and now I switch to this tab, I want this tab with ViewX to rotate to Portrait.